# Javascript - click on buttons to populate text box

Tags: php, javascript

This worked perfectly - found this example using a drop down box and modified - with some help of course!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> function moveNumbers(num) {
var txt=document.getElementById("result").value;
txt=txt + num;
document.getElementById("result").value=txt;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no"     onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="text" id="result" size="20">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you wanted to fill the textbox with 333? "Click on checkbox 3, then uncheck it, then click again"?

Comment: @raina77ow good question! 
user1916335 : show us what you have tried!

Comment: 333 - I guess I would need 3 lists of checkboxes?  What about buttons? Each time I click on the button it would add a value to the textbox?

Comment: What I have tried so far is to have 3 lists of checkboxes using PHP - and I click on each set to store the number before I submit the HTML form.  Trying to get it down to one set of numbers -

Comment: @GRicks - Consider adding your existing code to the question to show us what you've already done. That would allow us to suggest modifications to get it to the state you're looking for. As it stands, there's not enough detail here for somebody to give you a solid answer.

Comment: REVISED question is shown above now.  raina77ow had a good point about having to check and uncheck.  If I used BUTTONS instead - I would not have to go through that.  The code I displayed above shows 5 of the 30 checkboxes I have on my form .  Thanks.

Comment: So right now - I have THIRTY checkboxes that I check to create a 3 digit number - FIVE are shown above.  I am now trying to get 10 BUTTONS to create a 3 digit number in a text box - so when I submit the HTML form - it will post the 3 digit number.

Comment: This is where I am at now - @jackflash has it working in JSFiddle - but I can't seem to get it working in my environment.  Mootools is working fine - tested it before implementing code from jackflash - any help is appreciated!

Comment: This worked perfectly!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> function moveNumbers(num) {
    var txt=document.getElementById("result").value;
    txt=txt + num;
    document.getElementById("result").value=txt;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="text" id="result" size="20">

</form>
</body>

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="screen" />
<div id="keypad">
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <br />
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <br />
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <br />
    <button>0</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var screen  = document.getElementById('screen'),
        keypad  = document.getElementById('keypad'),
        buttons = keypad.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            screen.value = screen.value + this.innerHTML;
            return false;
        };
    }
};​
```

**Full example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="javascript: /* Just for testing */ alert('Sending...'); return false;">
        <input type="text" id="screen" />
        <div id="keypad">
            <button>7</button>
            <button>8</button>
            <button>9</button>
            <br />
            <button>4</button>
            <button>5</button>
            <button>6</button>
            <br />
            <button>1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
            <br />
            <button>0</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var screen  = document.getElementById('screen'),
                keypad  = document.getElementById('keypad'),
                buttons = keypad.getElementsByTagName('button');
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                buttons[i].onclick = function () {
                    screen.value = screen.value + this.innerHTML;
                    // Try to comment line below to see what happens
                    return false;
                };
            }
        };​
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTzY4/3/)

Comment: EXACTLY what I need - except for one thing!  When I use the JSFiddle link - it works exactly the way I need it to work.  But - when I put it in my form - it submits the form each time I click on the number.  I tried putting the code BEFORE the form - and it does not work...any ideas?   Thanks!

Comment: @GRicks Done! I've updated the JSFiddle. Just added a `return false;` statement into buttons' `onclick` event function.

Comment: '@jackflash still not working with my code.  I posted what I am currently using in my PHP file - thanks.

Comment: @GRicks I posted a full example. Sorry but I can't do anything else for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="app(1)">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2" onclick="app(2)">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2" onclick="app(3)">

<script language="javascript">
    function app(text)
    {
         var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("Mytextbox"); //Replace this with correct name
         TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + text;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KhwHY/1/

**JQuery**

```
$('input').click(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#Output').text($('#Output').text() + $(this).val());
    } else {
    }
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br /> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="3">3<br />
</form>

<div id="Output">

</div>
```

​This should provide you with a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

I did 90% of the work, you take it from here. http://jsfiddle.net/MeWhp/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
input, label { line-height: 1.5em; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="1" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="2" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="3" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <textarea id="log">
   </textarea>
</form>

<script>

</script>
$("input").click(function() {
  $("#log").html( $(":checked").val() + " is checked!" );
});
</body>
</html>​
```